# How to select and change only certain (same)values in attributetable in QGIS

Tags: qgis, attribute-table

I have an attributetable. Spread all over it are numbers like -99999997. I want to replace them by zero (0). There a many columns in which there are such numbers. 
I have used the expression (an example with one column P-Ant_ARU)

```
case when   "P_ANT_ARU"  is  -99999997  then '0' else    "P_ANT_ARU"  end
```

for every feature in the column but I wonder if there is a faster way to use in the field calculator to get rid of all the -99999997 in one or perhaps two steps, because there are a lot of columns  :-)

I have also tried *toint(0)* but that doesn't work because you have to choose a field, and I want a *value* to be changed. The same problem occurs with the plugin QuickMultiAttributeEdit.

So how can  I select all those numbers in the whole table and  make them zero.

[image: attributetable]

Answer (score 4):

Below are a couple of methods you could use in the **Python Console** which replaces all values in the *Attribute Table* of `-99999997` with `0`. As they are within a function, there shouldn't be anything printed in the console (incase this somehow freezes QGIS). After only limited testing, I found that changing attributes on a column by column basis was a bit faster.

- ### Row by row:

  ```
  def by_row():
      layer = qgis.utils.iface.activeLayer()  
      layer.startEditing()   
      for feat in layer.getFeatures():
          f = feat.fields()
          num = f.count()
          for i in range(num):
              if feat[i] == '-99999997':
                  feat[i] = '0'
                  layer.updateFeature(feat)
      layer.commitChanges()

  by_row()
  ```
- ### Column by column:

  ```
  def by_column():
      layer = qgis.utils.iface.activeLayer()  
      layer.startEditing()   
      for field in layer.dataProvider().attributeIndexes():
          for feature in layer.getFeatures():
              attrs = feature.attributes()
              if attrs[field] == '-99999997':
                  feature[field] = '0'
                  layer.updateFeature(feature)
      layer.commitChanges()

  by_column()
  ```

Comment: layer = qgis.utils.iface.activeLayer()  
  File "<input>", line 1
    layer = qgis.utils.iface.activeLayer()
   ^
IndentationError: unexpected indent
layer.startEditing()   
False
for feat in layer.getFeatures():
    f = feat.fields()
    num = f.count()
    for i in range(num):
        if feat[i] == '-99999997':
        feat[i] = '0'
  File "<input>", line 6
    feat[i] = '0'
       ^
IndentationError: expected an indented block.  Is what I get back.....

Comment: @Willem - Apologies buddy, forgot to indent after the `if` statement. Should work now =)

Comment: thanks sorted it out myself although Im not a Python user, but know a little bit of javascript and PHP + internet. It is running now and takes  a while and see a lot of _true_ :-)

Comment: @Willem - Awesome, glad you found another solution! You should post it as an **answer** as it could be helpful to others =)

Comment: Tried the script but after one hour or more it wasnt ready so I try to terminate the script. But there seems be some kind of loop. I had to close qgis. Tried it on a smaller file. But there wasnt any change in the values after the script ran.

Comment: @Willem - Huh...strange. Which QGIS version are you using? I am using 2.12.3-Lyon. There are a couple of `for` loops but it should only loop through the attribute table once (tested by just printing the values).

Comment: Also 2.12. Could be because it is a big table, and runs all the values as 'true'. But tested it on a smaller one and there was not a loop but the values didnt change at all, when I opend the table I saw the same values. Perhaps I have to do something els after I ran the script?

Comment: @Willem - Edited post to include another method which changes values by column instead of by row, I found this to be a bit faster. But you're right, could be because it's a large table that it may take a while =)

Answer (score 2):

Make an attribute selection in the attribute table e.g.

```
P_MAROKKO = -99999997
```

Then use the field calculator, check *Selected features only* and
the existing field and assign the value.

Comment: Thats what I did/ do allready with 'case when   "P_ANT_ARU"  is  -99999997  then '0' else    "P_ANT_ARU"  end' what you suggest is the 'same' way and not what I asked :-) Ill give the Python code a try.

Answer (score 1):

Open the `.dbf` file of your shapefile with Excel, LibreOffice Calc or something equivalent. Then, a simple "Search and Replace" should do the job.

Watch out the encoding format when opening and saving the `.dbf` file, though.

EDIT: **Important note** (following iant's comment): make a backup copy of your shapefile before manually editing the `.dbf` file, since this operation could break your shapefile.

Comment: Can be solved in QGIS.

Comment: As I understand, the author of the question has many attributes in his shapefile and wants to edit all of them at the same time. As far as I know, this can't be easily done in QGIS. That's why I suggested an external tool. EDIT: comment moved to the right section.

Comment: It's very easy to break your shapefile doing this if the row order changes

Comment: Yes I agree with @iant. Done that in my 'earlier days' with GIS and that went wrong.

Answer (score 1):

After trying to use the Python script which didnt work I went to the next solution mentioned above: open the .dbf in Open Office Calc and with search/ replace. It was a matter of seconds when the results were ready. No problem at all with the shapefile, so that's what I will use. My first fears I think of using an external program to do the job where based on the use of Excel , Calc did the thing for me. For smaller amounts of data in one column I will use the _case when   "P_ANT_ARU"  is  -99999997  then '0' else    "P_ANT_ARU"  end_ thing. Learned about Python though...